# c++ comparison not working... ! The code never stops executing

Tags: c++

Why would this code not stop executing??
So when I execute this code, the value of x is 1.0 as a point but this won't stop executing. Please tell me why is this happening..!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{



  double x(0.0);
  double increment(0.1);

  //cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  while (x != 1.000000)
  {
    cout << x << endl;
    x += increment;

    if (x >= 1.1){
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;


}
```

Comment: `x` will never be equal to `1.000000` because floating point numbers are not perfectly precise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: I tried comparing x to 1.000000 and I even added

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
 to the code, but it did not work!

Comment: in short: you need epsilon comparison.

Comment: Or change `while (x != 1.000000)` to `while (x < 1.0)`.

Comment: But I want to use (x != 1.0) or something like that !

Comment: I tried your code, it's working pretty well after compiling with g++, even if I used 0.000001 as increment